# Does the damage from Ursa's fury swipes cleave?

Tags: dota-2

If I get a battlefury on Ursa, will the damage from fury swipes cleave?

Answer (score 4):

No. The only attack effect (includes all Buffs, UAM and other modifiers) that works with Cleave is Critical Strike.

Source : http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Cleave